# How to change the code. verilog testbench code

Tags: verilog, hdl

I make a design for an adder but the result is wrong.

```
module FMUL(CLK, St, F1, E1, F2, E2, F, V, done);

    input CLK;
    input St;
    input [3:0] F1;
    input [3:0] E1;
    input [3:0] F2;
    input [3:0] E2;
    output[6:0] F;
    output V;
    output done;

    reg[6:0] F;
    reg done;
    reg V;

    reg[3:0] A;
    reg[3:0] B;
    reg[3:0] C;
    reg[4:0] X;
    reg[4:0] Y;
    reg Load;
    reg Adx;
    reg SM8;
    reg RSF;
    reg LSF;
    reg AdSh;
    reg Sh;
    reg Cm;
    reg Mdone;
    reg[1:0] PS1;
    reg[1:0] NS1;
    reg[2:0] State;
    reg[2:0] Nextstate;

    initial
    begin
        State = 0;
        PS1 = 0;
        NS1 = 0;
        Nextstate=0;
    end

    always @(PS1 or St or Mdone or X or A or B)
    begin : main_control
    Load = 1'b0;
    Adx = 1'b0;

    NS1 = 0;
    SM8 = 1'b0;
    RSF = 1'b0;
    LSF = 1'b0;

    V = 1'b0;
    F = 7'b0000000;
    done = 1'b0;
    case (PS1)
    0 : 
    begin
        F = 7'b0000000;
        done = 1'b0;
        V = 1'b0;
        if(St == 1'b1)
        begin
            Load = 1'b1;
            NS1 = 1;
        end

    end

    1 : 
    begin
        Adx = 1'b1;
        NS1 = 2;
    end

    2 :
    begin
        if(Mdone == 1'b1)
        begin
            if(A==0)
            begin
                SM8 = 1'b1;
            end
            else if(A == 4 & B == 0)
            begin
                RSF = 1'b1;
            end
            else if (A[2] == A[1])
            begin
                LSF = 1'b1;
            end
            NS1 = 3;
            end

            else
            begin
                NS1 = 2;
            end
    end

    3 : begin
            if(X[4] != X[3])
            begin
                V = 1'b1;
            end
            else
            begin
                V = 1'b0;
            end 
            done = 1'b1;
            F = {A[2:0],B};
            if(St==1'b0)
            begin
                NS1 = 0;
            end

        end

    endcase
    end



    always @(State or Adx or B)
    begin : mul2c
    AdSh = 1'b0;
    Sh = 1'b0;
    Cm = 1'b0;
    Mdone = 1'b0;
    Nextstate = 0;

    case(State)
    0 : 
    begin
        if(Adx==1'b1)
        begin
            if((B[0]) == 1'b1)
            begin
                AdSh = 1'b1;
            end
            else
            begin
                Sh = 1'b1;
            end
            Nextstate = 1;
            end
        end

    1,2 :
    begin
        if((B[0])==1'b1)
        begin
            AdSh = 1'b1;
        end
        else
        begin
            Sh = 1'b1;
        end
        Nextstate = State + 1;
        end

    3: 
    begin
        if((B[0])==1'b1)
        begin
            Cm = 1'b1;
            AdSh = 1'b1;
        end
        else
        begin
            Sh = 1'b1;
        end
        Nextstate = 4;
        end

    4:
    begin
        Mdone = 1'b1;
        Nextstate = 0;
    end

    endcase
    end



    wire [3:0] addout;
    assign addout = (Cm == 1'b0)? (A+C) : (A-C);

    always @(posedge CLK)
    begin : update

        PS1 <= NS1;
        State <= Nextstate;
        if(Load == 1'b1)
        begin
            X <= {E1[3], E1};
            Y <= {E2[3], E2};
            A <= 4'b0000;
            B <= F1;
            C <= F2;

            end

            if(Adx == 1'b1)
            begin
                X <= X+Y;
            end
            if(SM8 == 1'b1)
            begin
                X <= 5'b11000;
            end

            if(RSF == 1'b1)
            begin
                A <= {1'b0, A[3:1]};
                B <= {A[0], B[3:1]};
                X <= X+1;
            end
            if(LSF == 1'b1)
            begin
                A <= {A[2:0], B[3]};
                B <= {B[2:0], 1'b0};
                X <= X+31;
            end
            if(AdSh == 1'b1)
            begin
                A <= {(C[3]^Cm), addout[3:1]};
                B <= {addout[0], B[3:1]};
            end
            if(Sh == 1'b1)
            begin
                A <= {A[3], A[3:1]};
                B <= {A[0], B[3:1]};
            end
            end

            endmodule
```

test bench.

```
module tb_FMUL();

    wire[6:0] F;
    wire done;
    wire V;

    reg[3:0] A;
    reg[3:0] B;
    reg[3:0] C;
    reg[4:0] X;
    reg[4:0] Y;
    reg Load;
    reg Adx;
    reg SM8;
    reg RSF;
    reg LSF;
    reg AdSh;
    reg Sh;
    reg Cm;
    reg Mdone;
    reg[1:0] PS1;
    reg[1:0] NS1;
    reg[2:0] State;
    reg[2:0] Nextstate;
    reg CLK;
    reg St;
    reg [3:0] F1;
    reg [3:0] E1;
    reg [3:0] F2;
    reg [3:0] E2;

    FMUL u0(CLK, St, F1, E1, F2, E2, F, V, done);

    always 
    begin
     #10 CLK <= ~CLK;
    end



    initial
    begin

    #100 F1 = 2.125;
     E1 = 5; F2 = 5.1; E2 = 1; St=0;

    #100 F1 = 1.125;
     E1 = 5; F2 = 2.1; E2 = 2; St=0;

     #100 F1 = 5.125;
     E1 = 5; F2 = 3.1; E2 = 3; St=0;


    end


endmodule
```

The simulation results waveform.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fV9Fi.jpg)

I refer to the book.There is no code test bench.
So I made. But did't operate.

also CLK not is not changed.

please review the testbench code.

Comment: You cannot assign a `reg` type to a float value. It will be rounded to the nearest whole number.

Answer (score 2):

You have (at least) two problems:

1. Your clock needs to be initialised (eg to `1'b0`):

   initial CLK = 1'b0;

The initial value of any `wire` or `reg` in Verilog is `1'bx`; `~1'bx` is  `1'bx`; so `CLK` remains at  `1'bx`.

2. Your simulation doesn't stop. I added a call to `$finish` in the main `initial` block.

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/r4U